# Streaming live audio with jPlayer

Tags: jplayer

I am learning how to use jPlayer. I'd like to stream http://u10.sky.fm:80/sky_the80s audio using jPlayer.

http://www.jplayer.org/1.2.0/demo-08-oggSupportFalse/ demo works on Chrome 9. I tried to simplify it with the following code snippets:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#jpId").jPlayer( {
    ready: function () {
      $(this).jPlayer("setFile", "http://mp3-vr-128.as34763.net:80/;stream/1", "http://ogg2.as34763.net/vr160.ogg")
      .jPlayer("play");
    },
    swfPath: "client/js",   
    volume: 60,
    oggSupport: true
  });
});
```

Unfortunately, the above does **not** work. I am sure I am missing something since I am new with jPlayer.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Again, ideally I'd like to stream http://u10.sky.fm:80/sky_the80s.

Cross post it on https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/jplayer/yW7WoYtrxI8 last night.

UPDATE: The following code snippets work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#jpId").jPlayer( {
    ready: function () {
      $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            m4a: "http://mp3-vr-128.as34763.net:80/;stream/1",
            oga: "http://ogg2.as34763.net/vr160.ogg"
      }).jPlayer("play");
      debug($(this));
    },
    supplied: "m4a, oga",
    swfPath: "client/js"    
  });
});
```

But I still can **not** make the http://u10.sky.fm:80/sky_the80s works.

UPDATE 2:
The following code snippets work on Firefox Minefield but does **not** work on Chrome 9:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#jpId").jPlayer( {
    ready: function () {
      $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
              mp3: "http://u10.sky.fm:80/sky_the80s"
//            m4a: "http://mp3-a8-128.as34763.net:80/;stream/1"
//            m4a: "http://mp3-vr-128.as34763.net:80/;stream/1"
      }).jPlayer("play");
      debug($(this));
    },
    supplied: "mp3",
    swfPath: "client/js"    
  });
});
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in your debugger when you try this?

Comment: Is http://u10.sky.fm:80/sky_the80s an actual valid url? Do you need a session with sky.fm to access it?

Answer (score 3):

### Two things you could check:

#### Is the path to the swf correct?

Depending on the browser-capabilities jplayer chooses the playback mode (html5/flash).
Try using an absolute path for the swf, includeing the file-part - eg:

```
swfPath:"/static/swf/jplayer.swf"
```

and make sure that you can access it, in your case maybe something like:
    http://www.sky.fm/static/swf/jplayer.swf

#### Do you serve the correct MIME Types?

As written in the [Developer Guide](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-server-response) you should make sure to propperly set the mimetypes. Not sure if you have an issue there.
When checking the mentioned stream with:

```
curl http://mp3-a8-128.as34763.net:80/;stream/1
```

you get:

```
ICY 200 OK
...
content-type:audio/mpeg
...
```

The manual tells that you should set **audio/mp4** for m4a. (and **audio/mpeg** is used for mp3)

Maybe you could provide your current code with urls to running streams? This would make it easier to figure out what's going on. (The http://u10.sky.fm:80/sky_the80s does not work - at least for me...)