# Does JPlayer support RTSP streams?

Tags: jquery, streaming, rtsp, jplayer

I have an RTSP stream playing in a mp4a format, will it work with JPlayer? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it does: http://www.jplayer.org/1.2.0/demo-08-oggSupportFalse/

Edit also: [Streaming live audio with jPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994972/streaming-live-audio-with-jplayer)

Answer (score 0):

yes, but you will need to setup your own system. Usually this consists of polling your media server every 10 seconds to get the current track data.

"http://domain.com/;stream/1"